# Access Violation while parsing XML in Delphi XE2

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe2, musicbrainz

I'm trying to parse a MusicBraninz XML file in Delphi XE2 using the following code:

```
webquery := 'http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query='+escape(tracktitle)+'&artist:'+escape(ArtistTitle);

Log('WebQuery: ' + webquery, 0);

begin
  XMLDoc:= TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  XMLDoc.FileName := webQuery;
  XMLDoc.Active := True;

  Log('Report: ' + XMLDoc.XML.Text, 0);


   StartItemNode := XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('release-list') ;

   ANode := StartItemNode;
   repeat
     Result.Album := ANode.ChildNodes['title'].Text;  <-- Access Violation
     Result.Status:= ANode.ChildNodes['status'].Text;

     ANode := ANode.NextSibling;
   until ANode = nil;

end;
```

The XML file is fetched correctly and looks like what's below:

```
<metadata xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" xmlns:ext="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0">
<recording-list offset="0" count="1">
<recording ext:score="100" id="a399eec1-d45d-4505-b475-ead0da6cad17">
<title>Mestecăniș</title>
<length>359000</length>
<artist-credit>
<name-credit>
<artist id="8fb78a16-0cba-4175-8c92-d9645dfb007d">
<name>Bucovina</name>
<sort-name>Bucovina</sort-name>
</artist>
</name-credit>
</artist-credit>
<release-list>
<release id="22b00afc-86ea-445a-8805-b6bfa33da74e">
<title>Duh</title>
<status>Official</status>
<release-group type="EP" id="4e8fb87c-3760-48c1-a3d7-88e7a2c839fa">
<primary-type>EP</primary-type>
</release-group>
<date>2010</date>
<country>RO</country>
<medium-list>
<track-count>5</track-count>
<medium>
<position>1</position>
<format>CD</format>
<track-list offset="3" count="5">
<track>
<number>4</number>
<title>Mestecăniș</title>
<length>359000</length>
</track>
</track-list>
</medium>
</medium-list>
</release>
</release-list>
</recording>
</recording-list>
</metadata>
```

My question is: am I doing anything wrong here? All variables are declared and initialized OK.

Thanks,

Comment: You can't pass a URL to the `TXMLDocument.FileName` property. If you need to parse a remote XML file, you have to download it locally first through other means, like Indy's `TIdHTTP` component. In which case, I would suggest downloading and parsing the XML using a `TStream` and not a file on the HDD.

Comment: Thank, Remy for your observation. I was mislead by the sample code on About.com (http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/ss/xml_rss_read_3.htm) Reading and manipulating XML files and I did not give it much thought. Of course, this costed me big.

Comment: @Remy, you don't need to. It's enough to pass the URL to the `LoadXMLDocument` function as I've suggested in my (now deleted) comment and like RRUZ has in his answer.

Comment: `LoadXMLDocument()` merely creates a `TXMLDocument` and assigns its `FileName` property. That property does not support URLs, only local file paths.

Comment: @Remy, then try to run [`this code`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12767083/960757) which works for me in Delphi 2009.

Comment: @TLama: you are relying on a vendor-specific extension of the underlying engine, in this case MSXML on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an access violation because the `FindNode` method is returning a nil value and you are trying to access of a invalid memory location.  In order to use the `FindNode` method you must check the hierarchy (level) of the nodes to search and then check if the result is not `nil`.

Try this sample.

```
  XMLDoc:= LoadXMLDocument(webQuery);
   StartItemNode := XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.FindNode('recording-list');
   if not Assigned(StartItemNode) then exit;
   StartItemNode := StartItemNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('recording');
   if Assigned(StartItemNode) then
   begin
     StartItemNode := StartItemNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('release-list');
     if Assigned(StartItemNode) then
     begin
       StartItemNode := StartItemNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('release');
       if Assigned(StartItemNode) then
       begin
         ANode := StartItemNode;
         repeat
           Result.Album := ANode.ChildNodes['title'].Text;
           Result.Status:= ANode.ChildNodes['status'].Text;
           ANode := ANode.NextSibling;
         until ANode = nil;
       end;
     end;
   end;
```

Comment: +1, you were faster... Anyway, I think it's better to use DOM and XPath for this. Or a crazy looking `XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('release-list')` node selection. And `TIdURI.URLDecode` for URL encoding.

Comment: Off course, always I recommend use XPath for this kind of task.

Comment: Thank you, @RRUZ. I have never worked with XML until now and it really got me confused. You saved me a couple of hours with your solution. I appreciate your help.